How to fix an error in running rbokeh package?
I am trying to run the following code using rbokeh package in R. The package has been successfully downloaded, but when I try to run the code, it generates the following error.
Code:

figure(data = iris) %>%
ly_points(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species)



Error:
Error in lazy_(correct_value, pf2) :
is.call(expr) || is.name(expr) || is.atomic(expr) is not TRUE

I tried uninstalling the rbokeh package and reinstalling it several times but it still doesn't work.

Welcome to SO! rbokeh is no longer actively maintained, is no longer available on CRAN and the repo was archived on GH a year ago. From the commit history the last true commit was about three years ago. And the error you get is most likely due to the fact that the package does not account for changes in the dependencies (which also include several packages which have been retired) or R itself. Hence, I would recommend to not use this package any longer.

If you tell us what you are trying to do like a "tale" or a "recipe", we may suggest a code that does not use an ancient package.
